# remove word from Text to Speech c#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech

I put the word to microsoft TTS And I wanted to ask is there a code to remove a word from the list.

to add word i use this

```
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("dog")));
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("cat")));
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("fish")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UnloadGrammar()` method.

You should probably keep a reference to the grammars though, so you can unload them easily.

Like this for example:

```
var grammar1 = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("dog"));
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(grammar1);
```

And to unload:

```
_recognizer.UnloadGrammar(grammar1);
```

You might be able to unload a grammar like this as well, not sure:

```
_recognizer.UnloadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("dog")));
```

Documentation:

[`UnloadGrammar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.unloadgrammar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi! Did my answer help you? I would appreciate if you could accept the answer if it did. Thank you!